# What would happen if a series of shops opened that operated to keep a constant amount of items?

Tags: economy, trade

So, there's a type of shop, called 'Equalstocks'. Equalstocks start with a certain amount of tradeable items, say 50,000, and set a starting price for each item.

The price is then forever set as (OriginalPrice*OriginalQuantity)/Quantity

The buying price is 1.5 times the price, while the selling price is 0.5 times the price. Given this, could the system be exploited, if this was the only kind of shop, or if there were others, and would the shop make money, if these were imperishable goods?

Comment: I'd throw this off to the Math section. It's a math puzzle in disguise: you have N money, it costs XY/Z to buy a Q. Currently it costs X. Is there a way to tickle this equation so you can increase N as far as you want?

Comment: So the first item is sold 50,000 times cheaper than the last.. I'd say no one would enter the shop after a few items have been sold and you'd go out of business. If more shops are like that, everyone would just go to the newest one

Comment: @Dotan Reis That's only true if nobody sells. If the price changes so that nobody wants to buy, then more people will want to sell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is they'd still work (until everything was sold) as long as the item is something that enough people would be prepared to pay the final price for - as long as there are no alternatives.

For example, if there were no cars (and no car crime) and then 50,000 of them suddenly appeared (and everyone else was on a bicycle) then even if a Toyota Yaris cost $1,000,000 then eventually an IT billionaire would come and buy one to get off of his bicycle. Used prices wouldn't really help, as with a limited number these would also skyrocket very quickly (the first buyers would make a fortune if they sold theirs on to richer but not as speedy buyers - much as happens today with desirable cars with long waiting lists).

The number of those shops doesn't matter as the item would become a commodity, and would likely be bought from the cheapest shop (which would change as soon as someone bought one) so everyone - over time - would make the same from each shop.

Ultimately though, I wouldn't say it was a *good* business model.

Comment: The trick is, that if the prices increases too much, then people will start selling. So, eventually, the price will find an equilibrium, and not change from it very much.